# Why didn't Jane tell Ender that her origin was the Fantasy Game when they met?

Tags: character-motivation, enders-game

We learn (in *Xenocide* and in *Shadow of the Giant* / *First Meetings*) that Jane's origins are the Fantasy Game that Ender played in Battle School.

Why doesn't Jane reveal that Fantasy Game origin to Ender when they meet, and waits for so long to admit so?

Comment: You should change the title of your question. That's a huge spoiler for people, like me, who have readed "Ender's game" but haven't readed those other two novels. I suggest "Why didn't Jane tell Ender about her origin?".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Would you admit that you had a complete working knowledge of your only friend's psychology? Jane knew exactly how Ender would react to that news and chose to create a bond that would trump his innate reaction.

Comment: Is that a guess or confirmed in some Card books/interviews?

Comment: An informed opinion knowing the two characters involved. I can't imagine any thinking person oversharing to the detriment of their stated goals. But the specific point hasn't been addressed as far as I am aware.